# How to add pandas series as a data into another series?

Tags: python, pandas

In this code :

```py
import pandas as pd
arr=list(range(10))
s1=pd.Series(arr)
s2=pd.Series(s1,index=arr)
print(s2)
```

the result of `print(s1)` is this:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
dtype: int64
```

I added `s1`  as a data to `s2` and i specified the index for `s2` like this:

```
s2=pd.Series(s1,index=arr)
```

But  the result of  `print (s2)` is the same as `print (s1)`.
Then why `s2` does not have index and data of `s1` as a data for itself?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you create a Series from a list, the index is created by default from 0 to n-1, where n is the number of elements in the list.

When you create a Series from another Series, the index is inherited from the original Series unless you specify a new index.

You can create a MultiIndex (hierarchical index) object using

```
pd.MultiIndex
```

For more information, you can take a look at the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html

Answer (score 0):

Use s1.values to copy only data and not index